# Bootstrap mobile menu not opening

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

This is a wordpress site powered by the Secundo template and recently the mobile menu has stopped opening at all. I've tried removing recently added plugins to no avail.

Url is http://sparkengagement.com/

The theme relies on bootstrap to create the responsive mobile menu.

Any ideas on why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Bootstrap javascript.

Comment: Thanks!. Something's still messed up with the markup so it takes 2 clicks to open, but this is an independent problem.